# Rock, Paper, Scissor Ruby

Tags: ruby

Error:

> syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input end whlie
>   continue == "N"

I checked all the code, but I still don't get it.

Should I add the end code after `while continue == "N"`?

```
  begin 
      puts "|===============================================|" 
      puts "|Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors!!!              |"
      puts "|===============================================|"

      begin 
        puts "please choose one of the following: R / P / S"
        user_input = gets.chomp.upcase
      end while !["R", "P", "S"].include?(user_input) 


      com_input = ["R", "P", "S"].sample

      puts "You:#{user_input} Com:#{com_input}"

      if user_input = "R" && com_input = "S" || user_input = "S" && com_input = "P" || user_input = "P" && com_input = "R"
        puts "Result:You win"  
      elsif com_input = "R" && user_input = "S" || com_input = "S" && user_input = "P" || com_input = "P" && user_input = "R"
        puts "Result:You lose"  
      else
        puts "Result:Draw"  
      end

      begin
        puts "Play Again?: Y / N"
        continue = gets.chomp.upcase
      end while !["Y", "N"].include?(continue)

    end whlie continue == "N"
    puts "Good Bye! Thanks for playing!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `whlie` for `while`.

Also that `while` is checking for `N` to continue, what I suppose it must be `Y`.

```
begin 
  ...
end while continue == 'Y'

puts "Good Bye! Thanks for playing!"
```

If you want you could reduce a bit the `user` and `com` input validation, and apply a bit of DRY:

```
begin 
  puts "|===============================================|" 
  puts "|Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors!!!              |"
  puts "|===============================================|"

  choices = ['R', 'P', 'S']

  begin 
    puts 'please choose one of the following: R / P / S'
    user_input = gets.chomp.upcase
  end while !choices.include?(user_input) 

  com_input = choices.sample

  puts "You: #{user_input} Com: #{com_input}"

  regex = /rs|sp|pr/i
  choice = "#{user_input}#{com_input}"

  if choice =~ regex
    puts 'Result:You win'  
  elsif choice.reverse =~ regex
    puts 'Result:You lose'  
  else
    puts 'Result:Draw'  
  end

  puts 'Play Again?: Y / N'
  continue = gets.chomp.upcase

end while continue == 'Y'

puts 'Good Bye! Thanks for playing!'
```